# reliable delivery service - email, sms

Tags: email, service, reliability

I am looking at building an ordering service, this is fine but my question is how to reliably get the order to the shop. It is a fast food shop.

Are there any solid delivery options either via sms/phone or an email service that is pretty much 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the SMS providers like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) who give you web based APIs for sending SMS messages. There is also an API called the [OneAPI](https://oneapi-gw.gsma.com/) that is currently available in Canada but will be in other regions soon. You can use this to send SMS messages through a html API.
For email, take a look at some of the providers listed by [programmable web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=email), there are a bunch, for example [Yahoo lets you send messages via their API](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes make sure call back to sender for confirmation,...
check on my DMStar  CBuilder6 system.
 it fetch filtered email and sms QFree ordering system.
 Every minute or so will auto print out onto docket dot matrix printer as soon order received.

https://sites.google.com/site/dmsqfree/tastykebabs
or google it with tasty kebabs qfree

https://sites.google.com/site/dmsqfree/

E C and simple for small retaillers, no register of sensitive personal details needed.
 Using an old Nokia Mobile with prepaid $20.00 per year(free sms) connected into PC USB port,...

cheer.